# Where does exec block of doLast section came from?

Tags: gradle

I faced some snippet:

```
task senchaCmdBuild {
  doLast {
    exec {
      workingDir 'src/main/app/MYAPP'
      commandLine 'cmd', 'c', 'sencha app build'
    }
    exec {
      workingDir 'src/main/app/MYOTHERAPP'
      commandLine 'cmd', 'c', 'sencha app build'
    }
  }
}
```

Is it some kind of alternative syntax for typed task

```
task someTypedTask(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'ls'
}
```

Why does it work without type declaration?
Do we have some docs for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a [method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec-groovy.lang.Closure-) defined by the `Project` instance. It executes the command specified by the closure **directly**, so it can be used to run a command during configuration phase. In the given example, it is used to execute two commands in a single task (during execution phase via `doLast`), what *imho* should by considered bad practice.

There are other methods that execute directly and share a configuration closure with task types, namely `copy`, `delete` and `javaexec`.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec` you are using in doLast is defined in the [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec-org.gradle.api.Action-) interface.  The documentation states:

> ExecResult exec(Action action) Executes an external command.
>   The given action configures a ExecSpec, which is used to launch the process.
>   This method blocks until the process terminates, with its result being returned.